# Mocking Restangular with angularjs jasmine karma

Tags: angularjs, mocking, jasmine, karma-runner, restangular

I want to unit test my client side models/resources.

I use `restangular` and would like to mock it out and check/spy if the correct calls were made to `restangular`.

My resource:

```
module = angular.module 'myapp.core.resources'

class Messaging
  constructor: (@restangular) ->
    @resource = @restangular.all('messaging')

  send_to: (user, message) =>
    @resource.post(to: user.id, message: message)

module.service '$messaging', ['Restangular', Messaging]
```

My mock:

```
# Globally available
@restangularMock =
  one: jasmine.createSpy()
  all: (resource) ->
    post: jasmine.createSpy('post'),
    get: jasmine.createSpy('get')
```

My test:

```
# Set the global config before end of configuration lifecycle
angular.module('myapp.core.config').config (GlobalConfig) ->
  GlobalConfig.setBaseConfig
    api:
      baseUri: '/api',
      csrfTokens: {'messaging': 'abcdef'}

describe "Resources", ->
  beforeEach module ($provide)->
    $provide.value('Restangular', self.restangularMock)

  beforeEach module("myapp.core.resources")

  describe "#Messaging", ->
    messaging = null

    beforeEach inject ($messaging) ->
      messaging = $messaging

    it "sends a message to the given user id", ->
      messaging.send_to('test', 'message!')

      expect(self.restangularMock.all('messaging').post).toHaveBeenCalledWith(to: 'test', message: 'message!')
```

The error I get:

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got Object
```

Looks like the failure comes from loading the `restangular` module, where it gets the restangular provider object (ie `this.$get = -> ...`) and tried to run `invoke()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code:

```
beforeEach module ($provide)->
    $provide.value('Restangular', self.restangularMock)
```

is converted by coffeescript to

```
beforeEach(module(function($provide) {
  return $provide.value('Restangular', self.restangularMock);
}));
```

And the callback function in 'module' should return *undefined*.

So, change code to:

```
beforeEach module ($provide)->
    $provide.value('Restangular', self.restangularMock)
    return
```

[Converting angular-seed jasmine unit tests to coffeescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20520548/converting-angular-seed-jasmine-unit-tests-to-coffeescript)

Comment: Ahh Coffeescript you can be a tricky guy - works for me - Thanks!

Comment: How would you mock the restangular put method, as put is called on an individual message object (message.put())?