# Converting angular-seed jasmine unit tests to coffeescript

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, jasmine, karma-runner

As an exercise, I am trying to convert the karma unit tests included in the `angular-seed` repo from js to coffee script. In particular, I am having problems with the `tests/unit/directivesSpec.js` test set, which defines a simple value service. Here is my coffee script code:

```
 1  describe 'directives', ->
 2  beforeEach module 'myApp.directives'
 3  
 4  describe 'app-version', ->
 5    it 'should print current version', ->
 6      module ($provide) ->
 7        $provide.value 'version', 'TEST_VER'
 8      inject ($compile, $rootScope) ->
 9        element = $compile('<span app-version></span>')($rootScope)
10        expect(element.text()).toEqual 'TEST_VER'
```

There seems to be a problem when the coffee script code is compiled around line `6` as this becomes:

```
module(function($provide) {
  return $provide.value('version', 'TEST_VER');
});
```

And causes my tests to fail with the error:

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got Object
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.4/ng/areq?p0=fn&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20Object
    at /Data/src/ngfrontend-seed/app/vendor/angular/angular.js:78:12
    at assertArg (/Data/src/ngfrontend-seed/app/vendor/angular/angular.js:1358:11)
    at assertArgFn (/Data/src/ngfrontend-seed/app/vendor/angular/angular.js:1368:3)
```

If I remove the `return` statement, the test runs fine. Referring to the [example in the documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.mock.inject), it's not immediately clear what the module function accepts as a return value, but the `return` statement seems to be breaking things.

Any ideas of how to fix this, or would it be sensible to stick to plain javascript when writing test specs?

Comment: I think you should provide the original js code here. JS has an implicit return (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17337064/does-every-javascript-function-have-to-return-some-value) so I'd like to see the original code to see what's being returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Coffeescript implicitly returns the last expression from each function.
But you can add an explicit empty return statement like this:

```
6      module ($provide) ->
7        $provide.value 'version', 'TEST_VER'
8        return
```

which will compile to:

```
module(function($provide) {
  $provide.value('version', 'TEST_VER'); //without return
});
```

See also this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391493/is-there-any-way-to-not-return-something-using-coffeescript) for some more information.